# Cardview shadow redraws itself after rotation or rotten cardview

Tags: java, android

I discovered very strange behavior of CardView's shadow.
I just start to develop an app, and there is absolutely no any business-logic or something like that. But anyway...

I just add few views to my fragments layout, and discover, that after every screen rotation cardview's shadow getting darker. **After 5-6 rotations** it already looks like completely black. I guess, the problem can be somewhere in canvas, but no idea where and why - i even didn't start customize anything. 
I hope somebody already solve similar problem with cardview, and now can share that experience.

Thank you!

Here is screenshots, code, dependencies and xml:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iot="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/common_gap"
        iot:cardElevation="10dp"
        iot:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <DatePicker
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/common_gap"
                    android:calendarViewShown="true"
                    android:spinnersShown="false" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/common_gap"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/common_gap"
                    android:text="@string/choose_date_confirm_button"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java** (Nothing else in fragment class)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_choose_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

**dependencies**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utUCg.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely not due to any bug with `CardView` or its shadow draw. Rather, this is likely the result of multiple `Fragment`s with transparent backgrounds, stacked one atop another, and the darkening shadow is the additive effect of the shadows' translucency.

Active `Fragment` instances are automatically recreated when the `Activity` is, which happens by default upon an orientation change. If you're unconditionally adding a dynamic `Fragment` instance, for example, in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, that one will be added along with any instances recreated from the `Activity`'s prior state. Effectively, each time you rotate your device, you're adding one more `Fragment` to the stack, and the shadow gets a little bit darker.

This can be demonstrated with just a simple `TextView`, to show that it's not an issue specific to `CardView`.

`fragment.xml`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#fffbc02d"
    android:shadowColor="#70707070"
    android:shadowDx="10"
    android:shadowDy="10"
    android:shadowRadius="10" />
```

In the example `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method, we add a dynamically created `Fragment` with the given layout, as described above.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, new MainFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {
        public MainFragment() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This image shows successive captures after having rotated the device, twice for each step.

[image: screenshots]

If you were to put a log print in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, you would see that an additional instance is created upon each rotation. At the end of that sequence, we have eleven `Fragment`s in play.

One way to prevent this is to check if the `Fragment` is already attached to the `FragmentManager` before creating and adding a new one, which we can do by adding a tag in the `FragmentTransaction`. For example:

```
if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("main") == null) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, new MainFragment(), "main").commit();
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't need to dynamically transact the `Fragment` after startup, you could instead statically define it in the layout, and the `FragmentManager` will handle the check and transaction itself.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: You absolutely right! I created a bunch of fragments, i forget to check, is current fragment already attached. Thank's a lot for detailed answer, and very good explanation